# Android CardView remove padding

Tags: android, android-cardview

how do I get rid of this strange padding in the layout below:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryDark">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/ColorPrimary">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/korabltest"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/inner_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:background="#5c1b1b1b"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_nature"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:alpha="0.8"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Lexington"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_nature_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:alpha="0.8"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="527 (31%)"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you talking about the padding between the cards?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**UDPATE**

Well, seems there is a much easier way to do it, without guessing the padding and all:

```
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

or using java:

```
cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false)
```

You can read all about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setPreventCornerOverlap(boolean)).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

It is an intentional padding to avoid content from bleeding off the rounded corner of the card in pre lollipop versions (since clipping is not available). If you want to get rid of it all together you may use a negative padding in pre-lollipop versions for the `contentPadding` attribute of the `CardView` such as:

```
card_view:contentPadding="-8dp"
```

or using java:

```
int padding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
cardView.setContentPadding(-padding,-padding,-padding,-padding);
```

I'm not particularly sure which value will work seamlessly, you'll need to experiment and see for yourself.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but after changing card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap to false, rounded corners dissapeared at all and not it's just a square.

Comment: @IvanFazaniuk Yeah, I didn't try the `cardPreventCornerOverlap` attribute. Try it with explicitly setting the `cardCornerRadius` as well. Might work. If it doesn't, the negative `contentPadding` will do the trick: corners are intact. I did try it myself.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in XML?

Comment: Ignore that last comment

Comment: @fahmy the contentPadding only sets your content over the card margins. If you set the cardPreventCornerOverlap to false you basically get a card on which the elevation shadow is covered by it's negative padded content.

Comment: This worked for me:
https://android.jlelse.eu/using-full-width-cards-to-maximize-content-f739cb863ce8

Answer (score 8):

Please remove this from your code -

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Answer (score 6):

Got the same problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27668941/2069407) worked for me.

```
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

For device with API < 21, I had to make a custom ImageView class, override the onDraw to draw the round corners.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float radius = getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.card_corner_radius);
    Path path = new Path();
    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    path.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: What about reusing your Path instance?

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
cardView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
cardView.setUseCompatPadding(true);
cardView.setContentPadding(-6,-6,-6,-6);
cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I previously specifically defined the height of the cardview - after changing it to "wrap_content", the issue was resolved.