# How to remove extra padding of "CardView" android

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a CardView in my layout with `match_parent` as width. When I run the app in my Marshmallow test device its works perfectly. But in my Jellybean device, It is showing some padding.

I tried

`app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
 app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

But it is not working.

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wiinnova.cryptcoin">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name=".activities.ThisApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.HomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ContainerActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.TransactionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_transaction"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Fragment layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.wiinnova.cryptcoin.fragments.CoinsList_Frg">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pro_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#f00">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/main_top_card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                app:cardElevation="10dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_card_img"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Watchlist"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Evolution : Current"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/coin_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:refreshColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:refreshType="material">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/coins_list_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main_top_card"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android CardView remove padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299577/android-cardview-remove-padding)

Comment: share your manifest file.

Comment: I want a native solution. Not a library.

Comment: Manifest added.

Comment: add this line `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in your application tag.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/31300964/1223291

Comment: share your xml file.

Comment: `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` not worked

Comment: Why do you even need cardview if your design is simple and you want to support legacy devices? You don't even need its parent FrameLayout. Whole point of nesting Linear Layout in CarView and not using the core features of CardView seems useless.

Comment: I want to use  `app:cardElevation` for the shadow effect.

Answer (score 1):

reduce your cardview elevation size in your xml

Comment: I  want elevation in my app.

Comment: Removing elevation is worked, but not totally 2dp padding is there.