# How to remove white Color between two rows while setting up a recyclerView

Tags: android, xml

[IMG Of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P63E1.png)

How to remove the marked portion in the image given [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P63E1.png)
here is my XML code for the required
**activity_all_transaction.xml**  [Output of activity_all_transaction.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Fst.png)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
    tools:context=".allTransaction"
    android:background="#807D7D"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="55dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:background="#807D7D"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayTotalallTransac"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/lower_rounded"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.54"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dropdownoption"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        android:translationZ="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.042"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/displayTotalallTransac"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/menu"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**my_row.xml** [Output of my_row.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMGp.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/full_rounded">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/full_rounded"

        >



        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/full_rounded"
            android:elevation="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ttime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tid"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toperation" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ttime"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ttime"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ttime" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toperation"
                android:layout_width="151dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tid"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tid" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tamount"
                android:layout_width="206dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="188dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="188dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

According to me, there is some padding or margin issue but I am not able to find it.
THANKS FOR THE HELP.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299577/android-cardview-remove-padding

Comment: this value is too high `android:elevation="100dp"`, don't you think?