# MaterialCardView with top rounded corners should clip children

Tags: android, android-cardview, material-components-android, materialcardview

`MaterialCardView` clips its children when using rounded corners. If I use `cardCornerRadius = true` (which rounds all 4 corners of the card), the clipping behaves as expected -> children are not being drawn outside of the rounded area. If I try to round less corners (ie. only top corners, using `ShapeAppearanceModel`), then the clipping part is lost -> a top positioned child will be drawn over the rounded cornered area).

I realised that clip MaterialCardView calls
`setClipToOutline(shapeAppearanceModel.isRoundRect(getBoundsAsRectF()));`
inside of `setShapeAppearanceModel`, where `isRoundRect` returns true only if all four corners are rounded, so I tried applying `clipToOutline = true` on the `MaterialCardView` after setting the `shapeAppearanceModel` with top corners rounded, but with no similar result - children were still able to be drawn over the rounded part of the parent card.

What is actually triggering the clipping part and how can I force it on a top rounded shaped MaterialCardView?

LE: trial and error code:

```
// card is MaterialCardView
card.shapeAppearanceModel =   
    ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, cornerPx) // cornerPx = 24dp in pixels
        .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, cornerPx)
        .build()

card.apply {
    preventCornerOverlap = true
    clipChildren = true
    clipToOutline = true
}
card.invalidateOutline()
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? I've tried different things but it seems impossible

Answer (score 1):

After debugging the MaterialCardView source code I came up with the following sub-class that will prevent from additional offset to padding and unclipping to outlines.

```
/**
 * This view is for solving the MaterialCardView bug that in case that not all corner radius are of the same size
 * an additional offset is added to the card padding which causes undesired behavior(e.g certain child view of the card
 * that is aligned to the card top wont get it's corners rounded according to the card corner radius which will make it look like
 * it overlaps the card border at the corners).
 * Note that this bug does not occur when the corner radius is the same size for all corners!!!
 * [For more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824566/materialcardview-with-top-rounded-corners-should-clip-children)
 *
 * @constructor
 *
 * @param context
 * @param attributeSet
 * @param defStyleRes
 */
class AsymetricRadiusCardView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleRes: Int = R.attr.materialCardViewStyle
) : MaterialCardView(context, attributeSet, defStyleRes) {

    /*
    Method instance of MaterialCardView.setAncestorContentPadding via reflection.
    Invoking this method will allow us to set desired card content padding without
    the additional offset that is added when calling MaterialCardView.setContentPadding if
    the radius of all corners is not equal.
     */
    private val reflectedAncestorPaddingMethod: Method by lazy {
        MaterialCardView::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
            "setAncestorContentPadding",
            Int::class.java,
            Int::class.java,
            Int::class.java,
            Int::class.java
        ).apply {
            isAccessible = true
        }
    }

    init {
        setContentPadding(contentPaddingLeft, contentPaddingTop, contentPaddingRight, contentPaddingBottom)
    }

    override fun setContentPadding(left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        //override this method so that after calling super method for content padding which
        //will add the undesired padding offset in case the radius is not the same size for all corners
        //we will invoke the reflected to enforce given padding without additional offset
        super.setContentPadding(left, top, right, bottom)
        try {
            reflectedAncestorPaddingMethod.invoke(this, left, top, right, bottom)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.w(e)
        }
    }

    override fun setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeAppearanceModel: ShapeAppearanceModel) {
        //due to the fact that in super method if the radius is not the same size for all corners
        //the card wont be clipped to outline(which can cause overlap drawing of it's child views on card corners)
        //we enforce clipping to outline after calling super method
        super.setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeAppearanceModel)
        clipToOutline = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following configurationsif you use shape appearance overlay in order to prevent the childs to overlapping from the corners:

- Set `cardPreventCornerOverlap` to true
- Then leave everything else that has to do with the corner settings as default (just delete the values from the textboxes in the design mode).

Then you should see something like this:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that adds an extra padding, as you can see in your pic. I have a top child which should draw it's background full card width, and just be clipped card rounded corners. Also, as per docs, and what I've seen in the code, that should be enabled to work with pre-Lollipop versions, but mine's not the case (I use min Android 5).

Comment: There are no extra paddings in the source of that picture. But as far as I understand, you have a child of cardview but don't want it to be padded within the rounded corners. You want that the child to be expanded to the full width and be clipped from the corners. Is this what you want?

Comment: You're supposed to give some details; share what you did, share an example image of what you want to achieve etc..

Comment: Updated with what I've tried. The card is adding some inner padding between rounded corners and children views. (in your screenshot, you can see that the rect bounds of the child (containing Not connected label) are not as large as the width of the card.

Comment: I have seen your code, by the way is it Kotlin? Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31300964/12749998) answer your question?