# CardView inside NestedScrollView shows extra space in bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-nestedscrollview

I have some problem with a layout. I am putting a cardView inside a NestedScrollView and totally inside a CoordinatorLayout. And, it adds a lot of padding at the bottom. Can some body please explain as to why is this happening. I know that the cardView uses extra padding in below-L devices to show rounded corners and shadows, but does it need this much of padding and that too only at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.startup.practice.getplaced.activities.InfoEventDetails">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_event_details_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/content_image_height"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/info_event_details_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/manhattan_college_logo"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/sheet_text_scrim_height_top"
                android:background="@drawable/scrim_top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/sheet_text_scrim_height_bottom"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
                android:background="@drawable/scrim_bottom"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/info_event_details_appbar_toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_event_details_date"
                    android:text="12th July"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/date_text_size"
                    android:textColor="#90000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_event_details_title"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info_event_details_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Attention! Students placed in Amazon."
                    android:textColor="#ab000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/info_event_details_divider_title_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/info_event_details_title"
                    style="@style/Divider"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_event_details_desc"
                    android:layout_below="@id/info_event_details_divider_title_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/content_text_size"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Paste your layouts, please

Comment: try adding (padding="0dp") to the layout(s) and see if that helps

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [CardView has extra margin in each edge on Pre-Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068430/cardview-has-extra-margin-in-each-edge-on-pre-lollipop), if so - checkout the ["hacky" solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29148964/5908572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Used to have the same problem and I fixed it by wrapping the `CardView` inside a `FrameLayout`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_event_details_date"
                    android:text="12th July"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/date_text_size"
                    android:textColor="#90000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_event_details_title"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info_event_details_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Attention! Students placed in Amazon."
                    android:textColor="#ab000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_text_size"/>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/info_event_details_divider_title_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/info_event_details_title"
                    style="@style/Divider"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_event_details_desc"
                    android:layout_below="@id/info_event_details_divider_title_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/content_text_size"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you please describe how this solution works?