# ImageView don't match in cardView - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview, android-relativelayout

I have bellow xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_product_imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status_product_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_three"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative_two">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/select_spinner"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_product_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="TEXT"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/select_spinner"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/count_products_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TEXT"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/select_spinner"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_product_textview" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In above `xml` I have bellow `ImageView` :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_product_imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

**Problem**: My `ImageView` don't `match` in `cardView` (left and right and top).It has 2 or 3 space around `ImageView`(left and right and top).

In my source code I am setting Image like bellow :

```
Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(productsModelList.getPictureUrl())
                    .placeholder(AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(context, R.drawable.placeholder_pictures))
                    .fit()
                    .into(image_product_imageview);
```

[image]

Comment: A screenshot about what's wrong ?

Comment: Please check your layout file it has padding. Also the layout with id relative_one has width attribute as 'wrap_content" and it's inner child have width attribute as "match_parent".. Don't you think they are confusing each other..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CardView has extra margin in each edge on Pre-Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068430/cardview-has-extra-margin-in-each-edge-on-pre-lollipop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This space is the result of that `CardView` supports for system older than L (API 20). To make your layouts look the same either on the **pre-Lollipop** (and pre-`CardView` widget) or **Lollipop and newer**, Android introduced some additional attributes.

Because *overlapping* (rounding the corners) the content was difficult for older Android versions, the [`cardPreventCornerOverlap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardPreventCornerOverlap) has been added and has been set by default as `true`. That is why there're white stripes around your `ImageView` - you can check by yourself that their width is closely related to the `cardCornerRadius` value.

To remove this padding *turn off* **cardPreventCornerOverlap**. You can do it:

- **via xml** by `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`
- or **programatically** by `yourCardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false)`.

Keep in mind that this gives you the effect you want only for API 20+. 
On devices with older versions of a system, your rounded corners will be invisible (hidden under not-rounded image).

To know more check [the CardView doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html). In the first paragraph you can find the official note about your issue.

Comment: @ paulina_glab. Thanks a lot .